# GNU find from QProcess - Cannot use exec parameter

Tags: c++, qt, find, exec, qprocess

I'm running GNU find in a QProcess which works just fine.
Nevertheless, when I try to combine it with grep, it does not execute at all.

The QProcess is started with

```
process->start(findpattern.replace("~",QDir::home().absolutePath()), QProcess::Unbuffered | QProcess::ReadWrite);
```

When findpattern is e.g.

```
find "~/Downloads" -name "*.cpp"
```

this works just fine. But for e.g. finding all cpp files that contain "else"

```
find "~/Downloads" -name "*.cpp" -exec grep -l "else" {} \;
```

it fails

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of the backslash in `{} \;` is that the shell doesn't interpret the semicolon as a separator to the next command. This backslash will be removed by the shell and not passed to `find`.

But `QProcess` runs `find` directly, not through a shell, so that backslash should not be there.

From find's manpage:

> ```
>    -exec command ;
>           Execute command; true if 0 status is returned.  All following arguments to
>           find are taken to be arguments to the command until an argument consisting
>           of `;' is encountered.  The string `{}' is replaced by  the  current  file
>           name being processed everywhere it occurs in the arguments to the command,
>           not just in arguments where it is alone, as  in  some  versions  of  find.
>           Both  of  these  constructions  might  need  to be escaped (with a `\') or
>           quoted to protect them from expansion by the shell
> ```

Comment: I removed the backslash. I get a correct, nevertheless only one result line then. I need all results.

Comment: but it brought me to the right path. "+" instead of "\" seems to work